# How to use Qt5 QAbstractTableModel with QTableView such that boolean state is represented by disabled checkboxes which are grayed out

Tags: python-3.x, model, pyqt5

I have a `QTableView` with a `QAbstractTableModel` and certain checkboxes in some cells.
To obtain checkboxes for certain cells, my models `data`-function does something like

```
class MyModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    # ...

    def flags(self, index):
        if is_checkbox_like_cell(index):
            return Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | super().flags(index)

        # ... (other cases)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.CheckStateRole and is_checkbox_like_cell(index):
            return Qt.Checked # or `Qt.UnChecked` depending on model state

        # ... (other cases)
```

This works fine. Now I want to change this Widget-Model-Pair such that for the checkbox-like cells, the "model state" is fixed and readonly, checkboxes should display it but be not editabe and *grayed out*.

This is almost solved by removing the `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable`-flag in the `flags`-function, however, the checkboxes do not look grayed out. Is there a way to achieve this?

A solution which I find unsatisfying, is using the `Qt.PartiallyChecked` state, because this couples the data-side with a purely view-side problem of presentation.

Comment: You could try something like `super().flags(index) & ~Qt.ItemIsEnabled`

Comment: @Heike Thank You, this does exactly what I want. I didn't know that binary integer operators can be used on the QT flags, now it makes sense to me that the basic flags are powers of 2. Feel free to add it as an aswer if You like.